# BigQuery producing negative (!) zero when numeric 0.0 multiplied with negative numerics/integers

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I intend to do a CSV export directly from BigQuery, using the bq CLI (with flag `--format=csv`). I run into an issue where if a column with a numeric value is multiplied with a negative one, BigQuery returns `-0.0` (whatever that means) and this causes issues in the importing system of this CSV file.

Example:

```
> SELECT (0.0 * -1) AS result;
Row result  
1   -0.0
```

How can get I this result in `0.0` instead (of course the numeric value 0.0 will in most cases not be 0.0)? Is this a bug in BigQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#floating_point_semantics

> Arithmetic operators provide standard IEEE-754 behavior for all finite input values that produce finite output and for all operations for which at least one input is non-finite.

This is just standard float behavior. Other programming languages do the same thing:

```py
Python 3.8.2 (default, Jul 16 2020, 14:00:26) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 0.0 * -1
-0.0
```

```js
Welcome to Node.js v14.12.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> 0 * -1
-0
```

Be assured though, `-0.0 = 0.0` will still give you `TRUE`.